# How could I encapsulate request lifecycle events in Hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I've just started out with hapi.js and I love the request lifecycle events, which each tutorial / guide I read shows them like this:

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, reply) => {
    // ... these are great.
});
```

but obviously, I don't want to register them all in my `server.register` in my main script. I could do:

```
const lifecycle = require('./server/lifecycle');
server.ext('onPreResponse', lifecycle.onPreResonse);
```

But is there a way to encapsulate this further, to keep my main script lean and, well... clean?

Comment: Use plugins. In the plugin's `register` method, register the lifecycle events required for just that plugin - http://hapijs.com/tutorials/plugins.

Comment: While plugins are very attractive, I was hoping not to register a plugin for this.  Is that the only way?  or "the way its done" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most effective way to do this, and the preferred way, it to encapsulate the functionality in a plugin. Don't think of a hapi plugin as a traditional "Plugin". It's more of just a way to better encapsulate your code.

Organizing your code into plugins does a few things for you.

1. Forces you to more strictly encapsulate functionality
2. Makes re-use of code easier across projects
3. Makes loading all of your functionality into hapi much cleaner and straight forward.

Here is an example of what you're plugin could look like:

```
exports.register = (server, options, next) => {

  server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, reply) => {
    // ... these are great.
  });

  next()
}

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'great-things',
  version: '1.0.0'
}
```

In fact, when I'm building sites with hapi, I put all functionality into plugins in an `/app/plugins` directory, then break them out into separate Node.js modules if I need to reuse them across different projects.

Comment: To be clear, when I say *all* of my code is in plugins, that's not entirely fair. I have a `/app/routes` folder with my route configuration and handlers, but the routes are all loaded via a plugin that just loads each of the files in the `/app/routes` dir and loads them into hapi with `server.route(...)`

Comment: our setup is similar - everything below the launch script is a plugin. Launch sets up hapi, then registers top level plugins which each register their own and so on. The project structure is made up of directories with an index.js file and plugin files. The index is also a plugin that registers the other plugins in the directory - so you just require the directory and call register on it.

Comment: @Robbie - take a look at [rejoice](https://github.com/hapijs/rejoice). It's a CLI for hapi that uses [glue](https://github.com/hapijs/glue) to bootstrap hapi with pure configuration. It's not for everyone, but with large teams, it help prevent the index or server file from bloating because it doesn't exist. Everything *must* be a plugin.